# Laravel 403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server in production

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am having a problem with a website in production. I have been working on this website in a sub-to-dir and have now placed the project on the true website. But now I keep getting this:

```
403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
```

The website doesn't give this error on the sub-to-dir version. The .htaccess file which I am using in my root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can someone explain to me what I am missing? I have changed the `server.php` to `index.php` and back but that also doesn't make a difference. I have also tried giving all files and folder 777 permission but no luck.

Comment: show the path of this route in web.php file?

Comment: it's not an route issue, it's a permission issue

Comment: @AnnaJeanine Have you make changes to apache.conf or something to allow override?

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

edit the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/yourlaravelapp/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and restart apache, that may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just Re give the permission 
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/index.html file/